# Android: Distorted background for toolbar icons, list items and overflow menu

Tags: android, drawable, nine-patch

While developing an android app, i updated android studio and also android sdk.
after that, i faced strange behavior. when clicking on any item like actionbar icons, overflow menu and spinners get distorted background like picture below.

[image: َActionbar Icon after click]

[image: Overflow menu item after click]

my sdk versions are:

Android support repository 32

Android support library 23.2.1

Android SDK tools 25.1.6

Android SDK Build-tools 23.0.2

Android 6.0 (API 23)

SDK platform Rev 3

its same on emulator and usb device, and cleaning and rebuilding the project didn't solved the problem.

Also, i have not put any code in style.xml to customize these items and i use the android default styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i found the answer after a week of challenging and asking here:

i was using android gradle plugin 2.2.0-alpha and the problem was rised from that. i didn't know that it can be the source of such problem.

after returning to gradle plugin 2.1.0 the problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` and `android:background="@null"`
for the spinners and buttons