# selectableItemBackground shows black borders in pre lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-support-library

It seems that `selectableItemBackground` is broken all over my app for pre Lollipop devices. Not sure if this is a broke in a support library update. All widgets like Buttons, CardViews, RadioButtons, etc that show a selected state are showing this strange black borders when being pressed

[radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRee9.png)

[cards in recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDIDU.png)

And it happens in more scenarios like the back arrow of the Toolbar that shows by default. Note that API >= 21 devices shows the nice ripple effect in all the scenarios mentioned above.

I am using support lib v23.4.0 (I have already tried to downgrade to v23.3.0, v23.2.1 and v23.2.0 with the same results). My theme inherits from **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** and it does not set a custom drawable for selectableItemBackground. I looked at the source code and I was able to determine that the theme inherits from **Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light** whose selectableItemBackground is set to **@drawable/abc_item_background_holo_light** state list drawable which in turn uses 
**@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light** to set the **@drawable/abc_list_pressed_holo_light** as its drawable for the pressed state. The 9-patch image **(drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_list_pressed_holo.light.9.png)** shows this black borders, which seems to be the ones showing in the app.

I am seeing this behaviour in both an emulator and device (Samsung Galaxy S4) running API 19 (Android 4.4.2)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I find the solution at this url.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629817/android-distorted-background-for-toolbar-icons-list-items-and-overflow-menu

Comment: Thanks @SilenLi! I am using Android Studio 2.2 preview 2 and gradle 2.2.0-alpha2. I upgraded to 2.2.0-alpha3 and the issue was resolved in all emulators but still broke on the device. I did not want to downgrade to 2.1 as I still want to get the benefits of instant run and Android Studio forces you to upgrade. Seems like it's the only solution so far...